# How to force the video to stretch in android VideoView without losing video's ratio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

How to force the video to stretch in android VideoView without losing video's ratio?

If you don't get what I am asking. Here below is what I'm looking for. Picture 2 and 4 are what I have. Picture 1 and 3 are what I'm looking for.

[image: After_landscape]

[image: Before_landscape]

[image: After_portrait]

[image: Before_portrait]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution. I change Width and Height of VideoView to Fill_Parent.